# UpdateResource API - External component has thrown an exception

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to change a file version of one of my exe files, and for some reason I receive an error that the memory I'm trying to write into is protected and then I receive a message that the external component thrown an exception. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

```
   Public Sub ChangeVersion(ByVal FILE As String)
            Dim handle As IntPtr = BeginUpdateResource(FILE, False)
            Dim ver As String = "2.0.0.0"
            UpdateResource(handle, "RT_VERSION", "FILEVERSION", MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL), ver, ver.Length)
            EndUpdateResource(handle, False)
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Using Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648008%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#_win32_Updating_Resources) sample, linked from the [`UpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation, says you have to use [`FindResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648042%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [`LoadResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`LockResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before you can call [`BeginUpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648030%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`UpdateResource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648049%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

> 1. Use the `LoadLibrary` function to load the executable file Hand.exe.
> 2. Use the `FindResource` and `LoadResource` functions to locate and load the dialog box resource.
> 3. Use the `LockResource` function to retrieve a pointer to the dialog box resource data.
> 4. Use the `BeginUpdateResource` function to open an update handle to Foot.exe.
> 5. Use the `UpdateResource` function to copy the dialog box resource from Hand.exe to Foot.exe.
> 6. Use the `EndUpdateResource` function to complete the update.

(You're also not doing any checking of return values before calling the next function. If `BeginUpdateResource` fails for example (because you haven't called `LockResource` first, for instance), it returns `NULL` or zero, and if it does you shouldn't be calling `UpdateResource`. `UpdateResource` returns a `BOOL` that indicates if it was successful or not, and if it wasn't you shouldn't be calling `EndUpdateResource`. **ALWAYS** check the return values of API calls - they exist for a reason, and ignoring them is a bad idea.)

Comment: Agreed about always checking error codes. Since he's P/Invoking these functions from VB.NET, he needs to make sure that the `SetLastError` attribute is set to `true` in the P/Invoke definition. Then he can use `Marshal.GetLastWin32Error` to retrieve the error code in the event that the function fails.